my blog now displays only 2 posts
I'm currently experiencing a problem with the display of articles on the main page of my blog. I've set it to display 8 articles, which worked normally until yesterday. the blog is only displaying 2 articles. I've modified the HTML code to try to display a larger number of articles. Specifically, I've added a line in the code to set the number of posts to 8, like this
<b:widget-setting name='postsPerPage'>8</b:widget-setting> <!-- New line added to define number of items -->

However, despite this modification, I still only see 2 articles displayed on the main page.
This is my blog : https://gamingcultureet.blogspot.com
